# Explain what size_t(*)(const std::pair<int, int>&) means

Tags: c++

I read some code and stumble upon such string

```
ConcurrentHashMap<std::pair<int, int>, int, size_t(*)(const std::pair<int, int>&)> pair_table(pair_hash);
```

Could you help in explaining what `size_t(*)(const std::pair<int, int>&)` construction means?

Comment: Looks like a function pointer type... function that takes a pair of ints and returns a size_t.

Comment: Also see [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/)

Comment: @NathanOliver while very useful, unfortunately doesn't understand C++ gibberish :( There is the command line tool, however: https://linux.die.net/man/1/c++decl

Comment: @user2079303 Yeah, Fortunately you can normally remove the C++iness out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read it from the inside out:

```
size_t(*)(const std::pair<int, int>&)
```

the `*` indicates that the type is a pointer, then the parentheses indicate that this is a pointer to a function, the function takes a `const std::pair<int, int>&` as an argument and returns a `size_t`.

Comment: why `size_t(*)` doesn't has a name like `size_t(*name)`?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pointer to a function that returns `size_t` and takes a `const std::pair<int, int>&` as the parameter.

Quite often you'd see a variable name in the `(*)` part, although not when instantiating a template. Is that what's causing the confusion?

Answer (score 1):

It is a function pointer to a function with `size_t` return type, and `const std::pair<int, int>&` argument.